# align matrix with equation number

Tags: numbering

I'd like to change the numbering (5) to the right of the G_5 matrix.
While centering those matrices with equation numbering. Is it possible!?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{equation}

 G_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
 G_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}

 G_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
 G_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}

 G_5 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
 G_6 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}

\end{equation}\label{eqn5}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you count the number of errors you get from that input?

Comment: if you want always to have your equation numbers on the right, `\usepackage[reqno]{amsmath}`.  (some document classes default to left-hand equation numbers, although it's uncertain what class you're using, because the equation number wasn't produced in the "usual" way.)

Answer (score 3):

If I compile your input I get *twenty* error messages:

1. `center` is not only redundant, but harmful;
2. you can't have blank lines in an `equation` environment;
3. the `\label` should go in the `equation environment;
4. you shouldn't disregard error messages from TeX.

Here's a possible way to achieve what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eqn5}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
G_1 &= \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0
       \end{bmatrix}
&\qquad
G_2 &= \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0
       \end{bmatrix}
\\
G_3 &= \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0
       \end{bmatrix}
&\qquad
G_4 &= \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
       0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0
       \end{bmatrix}
\\
G_5 &= \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0
       \end{bmatrix}
&\qquad
G_6 &= \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
       1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0
       \end{bmatrix}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you don't want alignment at equals signs, change `\begin{alignedat}{2}` into `\begin{gathered}` and `\end{alignedat}` into `\end{gathered}`; also `&=` becomes `=` and `&\qquad` just `\qquad`.

[image]